# Manipulate soundcloud iframe widget

Tags: html, iframe, soundcloud

I'm loading soundcloud into my website using iframes. Is it possible to edit the style of the soundcloud iframe. Example. Set a class of the iframe to

> visibility : hidden

Or is there another way to manipulate this iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iframe is independent of the [soundcloud api](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/widget#). You can style you iframe anyway you want e.g [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/217833/390330). You can basically style the iframe inline using the style attribute. If you want to use CSS stylesheet you need to import it into the page using < link > etc.