# Stylize Soundcloud iframe widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, soundcloud

I'm trying to add some CSS to the soundcloud widget with no luck.

```
<iframe src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/213228373&color=ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&how_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false" width="100%" height="350" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
```

I tried following these suggestions, loading css via jQuery or javascript: [Manipulate soundcloud iframe widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610797/manipulate-soundcloud-iframe-widget)
but it didn't work.

I just want to change font size and line height of the elements. 
I looked also in soundcloud API but I can't understand how to achieve that. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you want more help with the API you can check my example in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625513/soundcloud-embedded-player-on-mobile/39698508#39698508 . You'll find a complete solution there using JavaScript.

Comment: @DaveThomas thank you, I will give a look to that! Anyway a less effort solution would be appreciated (if anyone has it)